# Prove that if $a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n \frac1{C_{r}^n}$, then $\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{r}{C_{r}^n} = \frac12na_n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove that if $a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n \frac1{C_{r}^n}$, then $\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{r}{C_{r}^n} = \frac12na_n$

Tried to use nCr = $\frac{n}{r}$(n-1)C(r-1)
But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You notation is double. I suppose that $C^n_r$ and ${}_nC_r$ mean the same thing, and that this is the same things that most people would write as $\binom nr$, and a bit fewer people (but quite a bit more than those whose use your first notation) would write as $C_n^r$. I would propose writing $\binom nr$ so that people understand.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The correct notation is C as the centre, 'n' in the top left corner and 'r' in the bottom right corner. But I couldn't find how to exactly do that so I put 'n' in the top right corner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$$

To go further:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{r}{\binom{n}{r}} = \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{r}{\binom{n}{n-r}}$$

$$ = \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{n-r}{\binom{n}{r}}$$

To get the last step, replace $r$ with $n-l$, do a little algebra and replace $l$ with $r$ (it's a dummy). Now add and...

Can you do the rest?

Comment: But if you are saying that replacing l with r, aren't you saying that r = n - l; l = r; r = n - r; r = n/2.

Comment: What I meant was after the substitution, you get $\sum_{l=0}^n \frac{n-l}{\binom{n}{l}}$. This is equal to $\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{n-r}{\binom{n}{r}}$

Comment: @user2369284: For the last step of Gautam Shenoy's answer, you just write every terms up if you don't understand it. You'll know that these two are equal.